# multiple-account managing on linux

Tags: user-management, chef

I would like to know how to solve multiple user account managing on Linux.

For example, I have few linux servers. Few employee have access to all linux servers with their own usernames.

When these is a new employee I should create a new user account on all server.

What is the best way to do so?

I use chef for server deployment.

Comment: Probably use openldap to manage posix accounts and set up pam to create home directories if the don't exist. You can then use phpldapadmin to create and manage ldap accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using chef and why not use it to manage user accounts? See here -- https://github.com/fnichol/chef-user

We use puppet in our infrastructure and use it to manage user accounts on 300+ servers.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use Chef; but then Chef has to know your passwords so it can write them to the filesystem.

The typical way to do this is delegate the PAM login to a centralized authority such as an LDAP server. Add the new user to your LDAP directory and they will be able to log in to all the machines.

Users can also change their passwords through the PAM+LDAP mechanism; I'm not sure how you would handle password changes in a pure Chef environment.

I knew this was possible but had no clue how to actually do it; I didn't have much trouble finding a sysadmin who knew the nuts and bolts.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but we use [FreeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page) and [SSSD](https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/) to cache the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I see several people have referred you to Chef.   The new Chef is Puppet.  It's faster, stronger, better.

https://puppetlabs.com/misc/download-options